# Local declaration of iOS 6 only pointers (e.g. NSLayoutConstraint)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, declaration, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an App which supports both iOS 5 and iOS 6.
In one class I need to declare locally some NSLayoutConstraint pointers, which are iOS 6 only.
I use them just for the iOS 6 layout, because for iOS 5, I auto-resize the layout.
This class is used for both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Is there a way to declare some NSLayoutConstraint pointers in the class' header file, so that I don't get an exception under iOS 5?

I've tried following, but I get a compiler error in my implementation file, that this constraint is undeclared:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_6_0
NSLayoutConstraint *exampleConstraint;
#endif
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions

Linard

Comment: As an aside, I'm surprised that you're using autolayout at all (even if only for the iOS6 app) if you're supporting iOS5. Why not just turn off autolayout altogether? It's not required in iOS6. If you have the layout working correctly in iOS5 using autosizing masks, then why wouldn't you use that when the app is running on iOS 6? If you have your app working on iOS 5 without auto layout, then why duplicate your effort by also having an iOS6-specific autolayout rendition? The non-autolayout code should work fine on iOS6, and it strikes me that your unnecessarily duplicating your efforts.

Comment: @Rob: I'm using autolayout to support iPhone 5 too. I could solve that without autolayout too, but I would need to have a 3rd storyboard anyway and maybe for the future there might be an advantage of using autolayout

Comment: As you point out, you don't need autolayout to support iPhone 5. To simultaneously employ both autolayout and non-autolayout is doubling your effort for no discernible benefit. Don't get me wrong: Autolayout offers some great features, but I personally wouldn't advise adopting it until such point you're willing to forgo iOS 5 backward compatibility. Pursue your dual autolayout and non-autolayout approach if you really want, but it strikes me as additional work with little benefit. I'd advise autolayout for apps that are iOS 6+ only.

Comment: @Rob: I see your point of view. My current update has iOS 5 backward compatibility, but I think with the introduction of iOS 7, I will support just iOS 6 and 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#if` is a compile-time preprocessor directive, it has no effect *after* compilation. What your code fragment does is only include the definition if `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_6_0` is true - so as you've set the minimum to iOS 5 this declaration will never be included.

However the solution to your problem is simple - do nothing, at least with this declaration. iOS/OS X use weak linking so you can compile code against a framework/type which is only available in iOS 6 and the code will load and execute successfully under iOS 5 *provided* you test for the type having been loaded. You can test that a type is loaded by calling the `class` method on the type, this will return `nil` if the type is not loaded.

So in your code you first drop the `#if` around your declaration and then and code which uses `NSLayoutConstraint` must be enclosed in a conditional which is only executed if the type exists. Something like:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *exampleConstraint;
...

BOOL haveNSLayoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint class] != nil;
...

if( haveNSLayoutConstraint )
{
   ... exampleConstraint ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. If I understood you correctly, just the line 'NSLayoutConstraint *exampleConstraint;' doesn't produce an exception. Is that true?